# Create Azure Key Vault Secrets with Azure CLI drops caret ^ character in value

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am trying to create a new Azure Key Vault secret using the Azure Cli v2.9.0 (we use this version in our pipelines and upgrading would be difficult at the moment.) via the command below,

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $myKeyVaultName -n $mySecretName --value "abc^def"
```

The command is accepted and a new secret is created but it drops the caret (^) from the string and results in a secret value of abcdef instead of the intended abc^def.

[image]

During my testing I have seen the below message from Powershell but it's very rare :
**Unable to encode the output with cp1252 encoding. Unsupported characters are discarded.**

Strange as tjhe caret is in the character set - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout

Is there a way to run this command and get Key Vault to accept the value with the caret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

[image]

Actually, it depends on your environment, this issue just occurs when you run the command in `Powershell`, if you run the CLI command in `Bash`, it works fine.

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name joykeyvault -n testkey12 --value "abc^def"
```

[image]

So if you want to run this command in `Powershell` environment, just use the line below.

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name joykeyvault -n testkey12 --value '"abc^def"'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy that works. Just out of interest how do you form the --value option if the string is in a variable such as --value @myValue?

Comment: @PhilMurray In powershell environment? If so, I don't think the variable way will work, not 100% sure,I recommend you to post a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I have raised a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any special value to store in AKV please use double quote under single quote '"abcx^09|"' instead of "abcx^09|"

AKV Stored Value = abcx^09|